# MAX primary and secondary?

Tags: mysql, group-by, max

With the below data example I want to group by the `groupcol` and within the group order by the `val` col and if no val exists secondary order by the `ID`.

Understand the first MAX value (sql below) but how to achieve the secondary MAX if no VAL exists?

```
SELECT ID,MAX(VAL), GROUPCOL FROM table GROUP BY GROUPCOL
```

| ID | VAL | GROUPCOL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 1 |
| 2 |  | 2 |
| 3 |  | 2 |
| 4 |  | 3 |
| 5 |  | 3 |
| 6 | 9 | 1 |
| 7 |  | 1 |

Would like to return this

| ID | VAL | GROUPCOL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 1 |
| 3 |  | 2 |
| 5 |  | 3 |

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  (With 8.x, it will throw an error (based on  default settings): "https://dbfiddle.uk/BlXRhdq0", see: https://dbfiddle.uk/F7i_ufh8

Comment: Strange. Using 8.1.2 but removed SQLmode settings.

Comment: How did you get the values for the column `ID`?  The column in your desired result does not show MAX, of MIN values ....

Comment: setting SQL_MODE to a non default setting will not guarantee correct results, see result of the last two queries in this DBFIDDLE: https://dbfiddle.uk/Iv3jYfKo

Comment: There will only be one result row per group, please explain what you mean by "within the group order by ".  Order what?

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical use-case for *row_number*

```
select ID, VAL, GROUPCOL
from (
  select ID, VAL, GROUPCOL, 
      Row_Number() over(partition by GROUPCOL order by VAL desc, ID desc) rn
  from t
)t
where rn = 1
order by rn;
```

[DbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OYONrgfr) example

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which value you want to return for the column `ID`, after you group by `GROUPCOL`.  MySQL has the *choice* to return either one of the values `1,6,7` for GROUPCOL=1. you should specify `MIN()` when you want 1, or MAX when you want to return 7.

But when you say: *"I want to group by the groupcol and within the group order by the val col and if no val exists secondary order by the ID."*, you have to do something like:

```
SELECT
   CASE WHEN MAX(VAL) IS NOT NULL THEN MIN(ID) ELSE MAX(ID) END as ID,
   MAX(VAL),
   GROUPCOL
FROM mytable
GROUP BY GROUPCOL;
```

output:

| ID | MAX(VAL) | GROUPCOL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 1 |
| 3 | null | 2 |
| 5 | null | 3 |

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/2ghnD66C)

Comment: Updated my answer after reading the first line of your question (again)...